# Can every maximal planar graph be obtained as a minor of a planar graph with only even vertex degrees?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

This question is about simple undirected planar graphs without loops. Starting with a planar graph ${\cal G}_0$ in which all vertex degrees are even we perform edge contractions, thus obtaining new graphs that are minors of ${\cal G}_0$ (and that are therefore also planar). The question is whether every maximal planar graph ${\cal G}_1$ (with arbitrary even and/or odd vertex degrees) can be obtained in that way as a minor of some appropriate ${\cal G}_0$ (clearly ${\cal G}_0$ will in general be different for different ${\cal G}_1$)? Also, if every ${\cal G}_1$ can be obtained in that way, then given a ${\cal G}_1$ how do I actually construct a ${\cal G}_0$ and a corresponding contraction?

Trivially, if ${\cal G}_1$ itself only has even vertex degrees, then we can just choose ${\cal G}_0={\cal G}_1$ (a graph is a minor of itself). The question is really about ${\cal G}_1$ that also have odd vertex degrees.

(I am only interested in maximal planar ${\cal G}_1$, but maximality may not actually be important for this question - but I am not sure)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by your correction of my earlier answer, define the operation of *uncontracting* an edge $(u, v)$ as inserting a new vertex $w$ in the interior of one of the faces of the edge and adding edges $(u, w)$ and $(v, w)$. This inserts one vertex of even degree and toggles the parity of $u$ and $v$. Contracting $(u, w)$ or $(v, w)$ restores the original graph.

By the handshake lemma, the number of odd degree vertices in a connected component is even. Therefore the following algorithm gives a graph which can be edge-contracted to $G$:

If $G$ has no odd vertices, we're done. Otherwise uncontract each edge along a path between two odd vertices, reducing the number of odd vertices by two, and recurse.